# How to plot X-Y graph in R (or python) with several data variables

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

Sorry for this naive question but I'd like to manage to generate a X-Y line figure without using the excel. This could be completely using for you but I couldn't figure out how to this in R (or python). I managed to do in excel using filter but I'd like to learn how to do it in R (or python) too.

Please allow me to explain my dataset. I have 4 patients that serum or plasma samples collected at different time point after keeping at different temperature. Therefore, in the first column I have the information about the samples and second column has measured value for X substance.

For instance, P1-P-0-4C shows **Patient Number** (P1, P2, P3, P4) - **SampleType** (***P*** for plasma and ***S*** for Serum) -**TimePoint** (O,2,4,24,48) - **Temperature** (***RT*** for room temperature and ***4C*** for 4 Celsius).

I'd like to plot all the data in the same plot to see if there is any change of X substance after keeping serum / plasma at different conditions. I'd like to generate a plot like this one[image: X concentration in patients after different treatment conditions]
My data set is this:

```
Patient-SampleType-TimePoint-Temperature    X
P1-P-0-4C   296069.0034
P1-P-2-4C   235396.4235
P1-P-24-4C  312007.7416
P1-P-4-4C   342862.3662
P1-P-48-4C  306989.3416
P1-S-0-4C   344062.9737
P1-S-2-4C   288759.3582
P1-S-2-RT   251556.5559
P1-S-2-RT   347681.0886
P1-S-24-4C  328497.3854
P1-S-24-RT  318663.7857
P1-S-4-4C   377022.115
P1-S-4-RT   300030.9723
P1-S-48-4C  322916.5035
P2-P-0-4C   302233.2476
P2-P-2-4C   212031.9071
P2-P-2-RT   280248.5514
P2-P-2-RT   200163.7082
P2-P-24-4C  304414.1135
P2-P-24-RT  288264.7509
P2-P-4-4C   266773.3594
P2-P-4-RT   267321.0591
P2-P-4-RT   315698.9957
P2-S-0-4C   324280.0475
P2-S-2-4C   298859.3902
P2-S-24-4C  317494.2878
P2-S-4-4C   363388.7028
P2-S-48-4C  334685.2213
P3-P-0-4C   309757.5704
P3-P-0-4C   365228.5421
P3-P-2-4C   345045.4865
P3-P-2-RT   315440.0989
P3-P-24-4C  228526.6513
P3-P-4-4C   374452.1789
P3-P-4-RT   334286.7564
P3-P-48-4C  329091.5618
P3-P-48-RT  294519.8679
P3-S-2-4C   299500.602
P3-S-2-RT   345366.8082
P3-S-24-4C  404017.0886
P3-S-24-RT  354502.5535
P3-S-24-RT  309955.0379
P3-S-4-4C   388544.543
P3-S-4-RT   301911.6627
P3-S-48-4C  402267.1695
P3-S-48-RT  296266.8484
P4-P-0-4C   118724.6213
P4-P-0-RT   103892.5857
P4-P-2-4C   119094.8588
P4-P-2-RT   105176.9063
P4-P-24-4C  126634.8397
P4-P-24-RT  115748.3037
P4-P-4-4C   133313.0945
P4-P-4-RT   120920.6753
P4-P-48-4C  110347.2253
P4-P-48-RT  210916.0767
P4-S-0-4C   291704.4734
P4-S-0-RT   305554.4509
P4-S-2-4C   256265.2956
P4-S-2-RT   250442.9917
P4-S-24-4C  271662.4038
P4-S-24-RT  255056.0136
P4-S-4-4C   245853.6192
P4-S-4-RT   197982.1819
P4-S-48-4C  269603.8002
P4-S-48-RT  171348.1218
```

However, I couldn't figure it out exactly how to do without subsetting and splitting the data? Is there any way to do it without splitting column into several lines?

Thank you very much for your help.

B

Comment: I just added python into tags hence python command can be helpful since I am learning python too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I started this before you updated with your actual data -- mine uses random data.

```
## Use the very useful ggplot2 library
library(ggplot2)

## Get your data into a data frame
## This uses random data
Patient.Number <- rep(c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"), length.out=80)
Sample.Type <- c(rep("P", times=40), rep("S", times=40))
Temperature <- rep(c(rep("4C", times=20), rep("RT", times=20)), times=2)
Time.Point <- rep(c(rep(0, times=4),
                    rep(2, times=4),
                    rep(4, times=4),
                    rep(24, times=4),
                    rep(48, times=4)), length.out=80)
X <- runif(80, 0, 100)
line.code = paste(Patient.Number, Sample.Type, Temperature, sep="-")
dat <- data.frame(Patient.Number, X, Sample.Type, Time.Point, Temperature, line.code)

## Plot the graph. Your data will look nicer than this!    
ggplot(dat, aes(Time.Point, X, color=line.code)) +
    geom_line() +
    ylab("X (ng/ml)") +
    ylab("Time (Hours)")
```

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpsu4.jpg)

You could easily adjust your data to the same format as mine by taking out the time from your coded "P1-P-24-4C" etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's going to be helpful. I'll try with my actual data let's see how it will be. Hope it works as beautifully as your example. Cheers. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Great to hear. Can you mark it as answered if you are satisfied. Thanks!